# #pragma warning(default: all)

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-warnings, pragma

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

```
#pragma warning(default: all)
```

This isn't valid as it is; I can give a specific warning number instead of `all` and that will restore that one warning to default, but I want to restore *all* warnings to their default. I don't want to write out a long list of all the warnings!

My goal is to make sure my code compiles cleanly, and that I'm not accidentally hiding any warnings in my own code that may have been disabled elsewhere.

Assume this is in a huge codebase, where other programmers have disabled warnings in headers (including precompiled headers) that I include but don't control, and in project settings or via the command line.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm afraid that you might already look the above reference. But, my suggestion is using the push/pop feature of the warning pragma:

```
#pragma warning(push) // The very beginning of your code
#include <...>
#pragma warning(pop)

// Your code
...
```

Push allows you to save every warning state at that moment, and pop restores to the original state.

Comment: I don't think this can work in general; for example if the warnings are disabled in a precompiled header. There's no way to put `#pragma warning(push)` before the PCH is included, at least in Visual C++. I'll add that info to the question.

Comment: It's simple. You can disable PCH for some files you want to control. In case of long compilation time, you can even create **multiple PCHs**. Create a header and a cpp file for the PCH with overrided warning settings. Change PCH settings for the files such as /Yc and /Yu.

Comment: That would work, yes, but it's definitely more effort than just listing all the warnings I want enabled, which also works. What I'm after is a method that takes less effort than listing all the warnings, but I guess it just doesn't exist!